# Dialog doesn't bring the json data like it does in the view

Tags: sapui5

I'm not able to display the data of the row of a table through dialog (fragment), following images of the code and a print of the screen.
I can't identify what could be wrong. When selecting the edit icon of a table row, a dialog opens with empty input fields without bringing the value of the selected row.

//MAIN VIEW

```
<core:View
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:model="sap.ui.model"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    height="100%"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    xmlns:sing="MyUI5WebApp.controls.signature"
    xmlns:custom="MyUI5WebApp.controls"
    xmlns:quillEditor="MyUI5WebApp.controls.quill"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    controllerName="MyUI5WebApp.src.pages.listaTarefas.ListaTarefas">

    <Page title="{i18n>Commom.ListaTarefas}" >
        <content>           
        <Table id="idTasksTable"
        mode="Delete"
        delete="handleDelete"
        selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
        items="{/}">
        <headerToolbar>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <content>
                    <Title text="{i18n>Commom.ListaTarefas}" level="H2"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                        <SearchField id="searchField" width="auto" search=".searchTasks" />
                </content>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </headerToolbar>
        <infoToolbar>
        </infoToolbar>
        <columns>
            <Column
                hAlign="Start">
                <Text text="{i18n>Commom.Edit}" />
            </Column>
            <Column
                hAlign="Center">
                <Text text="{i18n>Commom.Identificador}"    enableEdit="{settings>/enableEdit}"/>
            </Column>
            <Column
                id="title"
                minScreenWidth="Tablet"
                hAlign="Center"
                demandPopin="true">
                <Text text="{i18n>Commom.Desc}"/>
            </Column>
            <Column
                minScreenWidth="Tablet"
                demandPopin="true"
                hAlign="Center">
                <Text text="{i18n>Commom.status}"/>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
                <cells>
                <ToggleButton icon="sap-icon://edit" press=".onOpenDialog" />
                    <ObjectIdentifier
                        text="{id}"/>
                    
                    <Text
                        text="{title}"/>
                    <Text
                        text="{completed}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
        </Table>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

//DIALOG

```
`<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:model="sap.ui.model"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">
   <Dialog title="Selected Data" id="helloDialog" items="{/}">
      <content>
       <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplay354"
            minWidth="1024"
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="false"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="3"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="4"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1"
            >
            <f:content>
                <Label text="id" />
                <Input value="{id}"/>
                <Label text="title" />
                <Input value="{title}" />
                <Label text="completed" />
                <Input value="{completed}" />
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
      </content>
      <buttons>
        <Button text="OK" press="onButtonPress" />
      </buttons>
   </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>`
```

//CONTROLLER

```
 `sap.ui.define(
    [
        "MyUI5WebApp/src/app/BaseController",
        "sap/m/MessageToast",
        'MyUI5WebApp/model/RestModel',
        "sap/ui/model/Filter",
        "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
        "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
        "sap/base/util/deepExtend",
        "MyUI5WebApp/model/formatter"

    ],
    function (BaseController, MessageToast, RestModel, Filter, FilterOperator, Fragment, deepExtend, Formatter) {
    "use strict";
    

    return BaseController.extend("MyUI5WebApp.src.pages.listaTarefas.ListaTarefas", {

        _oDialog: null,

        onInit : function () {
            this.listModel = this.createRestModel("todos");
            this.listModel.get();
            this.getView().setModel(this.listModel);
            
        },

        searchTasks: function (oEvent) {
            var aFilter = [];
            var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
                if (sQuery) {
                aFilter.push(new Filter("title", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
            }
            var oList = this.byId("idTasksTable");
            var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
            oBinding.filter(aFilter);       
    },

        onOpenDialog : function (oEvent) {
            var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
            var oBindingContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext();
                if (!this._oDialog) {
                    this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("MyUI5WebApp.src.pages.listaTarefas.Dialog", this);
                }
                this._oDialog.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
                this._oDialog.open();
        },

        onButtonPress: function(oEvent){
            var oDialog = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
            oDialog.close();
          },

        handleDelete: function(oEvent) {
            oEvent.getSource().removeItem(oEvent.getParameter("listItem"));
        },
    
        
    });

});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
onOpenDialog: function (oEvent) {
  var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
  var oBindingContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext();
  if (!this._oDialog) {
    this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("MyUI5WebApp.src.pages.listaTarefas.Dialog", this);
  }
  this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
  this._oDialog.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
  this._oDialog.open();
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps solve the problem.